# How do I make the series label visibility conditional?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

Using Dataviz and MVC, I want to create a stacked chart (which is working).  But I want to only display series labels, IF the value of that series is greater than zero.

Here is the markup

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<ChartModel>(Model)
    .Name("chart")
    .Title("Pending Orders")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(false)
    )
    .SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults =>
        seriesDefaults.Column().Stack(true)
        .Labels(labels => labels.Background("transparent").Visible(true).Font("40px sans-serif").Position(ChartBarLabelsPosition.Center).Color("black"))
    )
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Column(model => model.OnTimeCount).Name("On Time").Color("Green");
        series.Column(model => model.WarningCount).Name("Warning").Color("Yellow"); 
        series.Column(model => model.AlertCount).Name("Alert").Color("Red"); 
    })

    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Categories(model => model.Day)
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis
        .Numeric()
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
    )
)
```

In the series defaults, the labels are set to visible.  I can't figure out what to place in there to make it conditional.  I've tried lamba expressions and that didn't work.  I'm thinking there has to be a way to access the series value, but I can't figure out how.

Here is the chuck in question

```
.SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults =>
    seriesDefaults.Column().Stack(true)
    .Labels(labels => labels.Background("transparent").Visible(true).Font("40px sans-serif").Position(ChartBarLabelsPosition.Center).Color("black"))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of resolving this by using a template as suggested above:

```
    labels: {
template: "#= (dataItem.Total > 0 ? dataItem.Total: '' ) #",
visible: true,
background: "transparent",
position: "center"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do it the way you are thinking, if you can you would need to use a template on the label with a conditional statement:

```
.Labels(labels => labels.Template("#: dataItem.Value #")...
```

Might be easier to just add a field to your View Model just for displaying the label and populate it with an empty string if the value is zero.